# In Swift, how to create an array of weak references to objects that support a certain protocol?

Tags: swift, weak-references

I am trying to create an array of *weak* references to objects that support a certain *protocol*. Below, the `WeakBox` and `WeakArray` are from https://www.objc.io/blog/2017/12/28/weak-arrays/.

The function `testingWeakStuff` manage to create a weak array of objects (`arr1`) and an ordinary array of references to the protocol (`arr3`) but it fails to create `arr2`. The compiler does not deduce that `MyProtocol` is of class type.

How to fix this problem?

```
final class WeakBox<A: AnyObject> {
    weak var unbox: A?
    init(_ value: A) {
        unbox = value
    }
}

struct WeakArray<T: AnyObject> {
    private var items: [WeakBox<T>] = []
    
    init(){
    
    }
    init(_ elements: [T]) {
        items = elements.map { WeakBox($0) }
    }
}

protocol MyProtocol : AnyObject {
    func f();
}

class AClass : MyProtocol {
    func f() {
        print("Hello, world!")
    }
}


func testingWeakStuff(){        
    var arr1 = WeakArray<AClass>()
    var arr2 = WeakArray<MyProtocol>() // 'WeakArray' requires that 'any MyProtocol' be a class type
    var arr3 = [MyProtocol]()
}
```